# @Transactional has no effect in my Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

This is a pretty confusing one. I've read dozens of links that purport to explain how to use @Transactional but I've verified no transaction is being created.

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.mypackage")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages=["com.mypackage"])
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

SubscriptionController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/api/subscription")
@RestController
public class SubscriptionController {
    @Autowired SubscriptionService subscriptionService;
    Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    public Collection<Subscriptions> subscribe(...) {
        log.info("transName: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName + ", isAlive: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        return subscriptionService.getAllSubscriptions();
    }
}
```

SubscriptionService.java

```
@Service
public class SubscriptionService {
    @Transactional public Collection<Subscription> getAllSubscriptions() {
        log.info("transName: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName() + ", isAlive: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        //return subscriptions via JPQL queries here
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def springVersion = '5.0.3.RELEASE'
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:${springVersion}", exclude
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:${springVersion}", exclude
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:${springVersion}", exclude
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:${springVersion}", exclude
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.5.RELEASE', exclude
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.1'
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:1.2.2'
}
```

So when I run the api call, I get null, false as the log output. The contract for @Transactional says that the transactional aspect code will be weaved into the annotated transactional method, such that there will be a transaction (and thus an entitymanager and db connection) set up before the method and closed some time afterward. But that is irrelevant becuase shouldn't spring be creating an entitymanager before the controller is run? Both things aren't working here. Neither spring, nor @Transactional, is setting up any transaction. This results in failure to do any kind of query except for what's doable via a subclasses of JpaRepository. Somehow my Jpa repositories are able to set up transactions for their own methods. But what if their results have lazily initialized properties? I need a hibernate session to get those. So I need a transaction.

Comment: Did you annotate `SubscriptionService` as a spring menaged bean (`@Service`, `@Component` etc)?

Comment: @NiVeR yes I did. Updating code in post...

Comment: What you mean by initialize subscriptionservice in your controller?

Comment: @VitaliiMuzalevskyi I used "@Autowired". Updated code so you can see. Thx for comment

Comment: what do you actually do in your sevice method?could you add code?

Comment: @VladMamaev it's alot of code. But it shouldn't matter, what matters is there is no transaction inside of a "@Transactional" method. Right?

Comment: ok, set property logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=TRACE , this could give you more information

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. See [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/52629424). Are you sure you have posted actual code? For instance, is the code really `public class SubscriptionService { ... }`, or is it `public class SubscriptionServiceImpl implements SubscriptionService { ... }`?

Comment: @Calicoder, you may also want to review [my notes](https://manish-in-java.github.io/manish-in-java/page/spring/transactions.html) on getting declarative transaction management with Spring to work and comparing them against your code.

Comment: @manish thanks, I'll have a look. Much appreciated

Comment: Since your class is not `@Transactional`, you should either have an interface to create a proxy or also mark class `@Transactional`

Answer (score 1):

What class are you using for `@Transactional`?
You should use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

Comment: I'm using javax.transaction.Transactional. This is the JPA class, right?

Comment: I changed it to org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional. The effect is the same. null, false are shown in log output.

Comment: @Calicoder can you put whole code with all imports somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.mypackage")
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

SpringBoot should do those things automatically

Comment: Just removed them. The effect is the same. I had added those, thinking maybe they made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

An out-of-the-box Spring-boot application using spring initializer (https://start.spring.io/) will handle transactions properly.  If you make yourself a sandbox with a unit test you can observer that the transaction demarcation done in your example will produce a transaction.  Here is my git hub example: https://github.com/skjenco/hibernateSandbox.git

Code:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test() {

    logger.info(TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName());
    .....
```

For transaction demarcation to work you must be in an object managed by a Spring (Component, Service, Managed Beans, etc).  In the case above it appears that you are in a Spring managed service.  Using a working sandbox may be helpful in trouble shooting your issue--that is what I have done to solve perplexing hibernate issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to post your `pom.xml` file. `spring-data` or `spring-tx` dependency should be added for auto configurer to create transaction manager. Otherwise explicitly create a transaction manager bean and run the code again.

You can enable `TRACE` level logs for `org.springframework` and see if transaction manager is initialized. 
Also check transaction interceptor logs. Use `logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE`